# StringReplace behavoir on iOS

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I have a `TEdit` box and in it's `KeyUp` event i am replacing any occurrence of `"-"` with a blank, `""`.  When i run on Win32 it works exactly as i expect - anytime i type the `-` key it shows up briefly and then is removed.

When i run on iOS and repeatedly press the `-` key i get the result of deleting the last character in the Edit box **every other** time i press `-`.  The exception is the 2nd and 3rd presses in which i delete the last character both times. It should just be removing the `-`.

e.g.  If i start out with `123456` in the Edit and start pressing just the minus key i get what you see in this gif below:

[image]

In tabular form the results are these:

[image]

```
void __fastcall TForm1::EditConstantKeyUp(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, System::WideChar &KeyChar,
      TShiftState Shift)
{
 if (KeyChar == 45) {  // minus key pressed  (ascii code for that key is 45)
 EditConstant->Text = StringReplace(EditConstant->Text, "-", "", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
}
```

What fundamental thing am i missing here? I'm working in Rad Studio 10.3.2 using C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *correct* way to handle this is to set the `Key`/`KeyChar` parameter to 0 to dismiss the keystroke, and not manipulate the `TEdit::Text` at all.

Try something like this:

```cpp
// or, use the OnKeyDown event instead...
void __fastcall TForm1::EditConstantKeyUp(TObject *Sender,
    WORD &Key, System::WideChar &KeyChar, TShiftState Shift)
{
    if (Key == 0)
    {
        if (KeyChar == _D('-'))
            KeyChar = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((Key == vkMinus) || (Key == vkSubtract))
            Key = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, that solved it when i put your code in the KeyDown event as you suggested.  Didn't work when put in the KeyUp.